# Codeigniter search engine mistake

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search

Hello guys i need a little help.

What i'm trying to do here is to make search engine to my posts

**where in my database i have**

```
title assignation price
```

Where assignation when posting can have different values like :

```
buying
selling
renting
for renting
etc.
```

In my view i have input field to search the post title and 4 checkboxes where when i check the first check box which is buying i get all results from the posts who have assignation buying. But when i check also to see and buying and selling posts i dont get any results.

This also happening when i check selling i get also the selling results which is okay but when i have checked more like buying selling renting i dont get any results.

How can i fix this.
Here is my model function :

```
    if($this->input->get('keyword')){
            $this->db->like('posts.title',$keyword);
            }
            if($this->input->get('assignation_buying')){
                $this->db->like('assignation',$assignation_buying);
            }
            if($this->input->get('assignation_selling')){
                $this->db->or_like('assignation',$assignation_selling);
            }
            if($this->input->get('assignation_renting')){
                $this->db->or_like('assignation',$assignation_renting);

                }
                if($this->input->get('assignation_for_renting')){
                   $this->db->or_like('assignation',$assignation_for_renting);
                }   

}
```

**Or for an example if i select the both selling and buying only the second one is selected which is selling**
Is this the correct usage here in theese cases?

Thanks, Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're not sending correctly the data from the view. Please, post your view, for checking what you're sending to the PHP. Anyway, you should check what SQL you're executing against the database.

In the method of your model, write:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

This will output the SQL you're sending, and maybe will point you to a solution.

Provide more info, and we'll be able to help you more, ;)

#### UPDATE

I've seen the mistake, :D, you're using variables but you want to look for strings in the field. With empty values the SQL is understanding that you want the rows with nothing on it.

You just have to change the code to:

```
    if($this->input->get('keyword')){
      $this->db->like('posts.title',$keyword);          

      if($this->input->get('assignation_buying')){
        $this->db->or_like('assignation','buying');
      }
      if($this->input->get('assignation_selling')){
        $this->db->or_like('assignation','selling');
      }
      if($this->input->get('assignation_renting')){
        $this->db->or_like('assignation','renting');
      }
      if($this->input->get('assignation_for_renting')){
        $this->db->or_like('assignation','for_renting');
      }   
    }
```